# Angular - How to pass parameters to TypeScript base Class

Tags: angular, typescript, class, abstract

To use dependence injection in Angular's Services/ Components/ Directive and other structures, you need to `Import` other structures and then list them in the constructor.
For example (injecting `Title` service):

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private _titleService: Title) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._titleService.setTitle("I'm the Home Page"); // use injected service
  }
}
```

Now I want to create polymorphic family with base class and drive classes, where I inject external services into the base class, and in addition I wont to pass parameters from the drive class to the base class

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({ ... })
export class BaseService {
  public constructor(
    private _titleService: Title,
    private _message: string) {
    console.log("Hello, I'm Base class. Message from Drive class: " + _message);
  }
}

@Component({ ... })
export class DriveService extends BaseService {
  public constructor() {
    const message = "Hello from Drive class";
    super(message); // <-- Error, missing parameter!  
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error in the `DriveService` from the call to the `BaseService` because I don't pass the titleService.
Now I **don't want to pass the titleService from all the child** class of BaseService. I want to **only** import and inject the titleService **once** at the BaseService code, and only pass the _message parameter from all the children class.

Is this possible? if so how? or should I import the TitleService and inject it in each instance of my DriveClass

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject all base class dependencies into the classes that extend the base class. Also, `super` has to be called first in the constructor.

```js
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({ ... })
export class BaseService {
  public constructor(
    private _titleService: Title,
    private _message: string) {
    console.log("Hello, I'm Base class. Message from Drive class: " + _message);
  }
}

@Component({ ... })
export class DriveService extends BaseService {
  public constructor(titleService: Title) {
    super(titleService, "Hello from Drive class");
  }
}
```

I've not addressed the fact that you've decorated classes called `xxxService` with `@Component()`, just the fact of how you inject dependencies into base classes.

Comment: Do I **have** to inject all dependence to drive class? can't I only inject once to the base class, and omit the injection into the drive class???

Comment: You have to inject everything that's going to be used. From Angular's point of view it only sees the top level class that it needs to instantiate. That class then passes down everything the base class needs.